# I am trying to load images in tensorflow. tf.train.string_input_producer function of tensorflow is giving conversion of fifoqueue to tensor error

Tags: tensorflow

TypeError: Fetch argument  has invalid type , must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a FIFOQueue into a Tensor or Operation.)

This is error which I am getting while using tf.train.string_input_producer.
I have images in folder apple2orange/trainA. What is the solution

I tried alternatives to read images with tf.gfile.Glob("./apple2orange/trainA/") but no luck 
I tried to convert output of to tf.train.match_filenames_once to tensor using tf.convert_to_tensor(filenames_A). but after using converting function , tf.train.string_input_producer is giving same error.
'''

```
import tensorflow as tf

filenames_A 
=tf.train.match_filenames_once("./apple2orange/trainA/*.jpg/")
size = tf.size(filenames_A)
shape = tf.shape(filenames_A)

#read = tf.gfile.Glob("./apple2orange/trainA/")
#imageread = tf.WholeFileReader(filenames_A)
#convert = tf.convert_to_tensor(filenames_A)
#filename_queue_A = tf.train.string_input_producer(convert)

filename_queue_A = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames_A) 
#giving (train.string_input_producer) error
imageread = tf.WholeFileReader(filename_queue_A)
init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)
    sess.run(filenames_A)
    sess.run(size)
    sess.run(shape)
    #print (sess.run(read))
    #sess.run(imageread)

    #sess.run(convert)
    print(sess.run(filename_queue_A))
    #sess.run(imageread)
```

A queue with the output strings should come.